# Google places use viewport instead of radius

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

How can I use the viewport to find places with google maps api instead of radius, the radius method is not much accurate for me.

I.e. I used the type restriction to only get nigh_club within a 50.000 meters radius in london and I did not get ministry of sound in my markers.

If anyone have a suggestion about how to refine and place request I will be glad.

**NOTE:** search request

```
var request = {
  location: location,
  radius: 3000,
  //types: ['night_club, bar']
  keyword: 'night+club'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LatLngBounds` to define your `location` based on the SW and NE coordinates that define your viewport, instead of `LatLng` + `radius`.

```
var viewport = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(southLat, westLng), // SW
    new google.maps.LatLng(northLat, eastLng)  // NE
);

var request = {
    location: viewport,
    // types: ['night_club', 'bar'] 
    keyword: 'night club'
};
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Comment: Just added an example to the answer. It's not tested but you get the idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current viewport radius using this function

What I'm doing here is getting the center and the northeast point of the current viewport in google maps, then I calculate the distance between those two points and that's it. The result is given in `meters`

```
var bounds = window.map.getBounds();
var ne_bounds = bounds.getNorthEast();
var center = bounds.getCenter();
var radius = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center, ne_bounds);
```

You can also check this by creating a circle like this

```
function draw_map_bounds_circle() {
  var bounds = window.map.getBounds();
  var ne_bounds = bounds.getNorthEast();
  var circle_center = bounds.getCenter();
  var circle_radius = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(circle_center, ne_bounds);
  
  const newCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: "#7CA0C0",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#7CA0C0",
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: window.map,
    center: circle_center,
    radius: circle_radius
  });
}
```

NOTE:
make sure you import the geometry library from google maps API. ref. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry